# conflict in jquery for sorting of gridview

Tags: jquery

I want to search my gridview with `jquery`
  I had written code as

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        try {

            $("#grdReq").tablesorter();
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    });
```

I am getting error `TypeError: $(...) is null` and in **google chrome** `typeerror: cannot call method tablesort of null`.

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 0):

When u are working with server control use `ClientID` to get the control

```
$("#<%=grdReq.ClientID %>")
```

or
     [attribute-ends-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)

```
 $("[id$='grdReq']")  //without using ClientID
```

Your code Here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        try {

            $("#<%=grdReq.ClientID %>").tablesorter();
        }
        catch (ex) {
            alert(ex);
        }
    });
```

[**GridView and TableSorter**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/30011/Sortable-GridView-using-jQuery-s-TableSorter)

Comment: In google chrome I am getting error like typeerror: cannot call method tablesort of null

Comment: have use added reference of tablesorter?

Comment: Ya I had added reference